# Error Using CommandType

Tags: c#, sqlcommand

I run this procedure in VS2010 all the time, but I just started using VS2015 and am now getting this error

> 'CommandType' does not exist in the current context

Below is my fully synatx, why does this code not work in VS2015

```
public static void RunStoredProc()
{
    using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(ConnectionString))
    {
        connection.Open();
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("RunUSP", connection);
        cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
        cmd.CommandTimeout = 600;
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
    }
}
```

**EDIT**
See image below, when I hover, no light bulb appears?
[image]

Comment: You are missing _using System.Data;_

Comment: You should learn to hover the mouse over the squiggly line, then over the light bulb, it will give you the option to add a **using System.Data**

Comment: Or Ctrl + . on the keyboard

Comment: @Steve - adding in the using System.Data statement remedied.  Thank you